# Удаление класса по маске (шаблону)

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть HTML:

```
<div class="row1 td status_check status_waiting">
```

Необходимо найти, если есть класс в div-е, если он начинается на "status", удалить.

Попробовал хотя бы просто найти, но не работает:

```
if (!$("div").attr('class').match(/status\-.+?\b/))alert('OK');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Максим147, так у вас в регулярном выражении в качестве разделителя используется `-`, а по факту используется `_`.

Подобный вопрос был на `stackoverflow`: "**[jQuery - Remove all classes with similar names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692142/jquery-remove-all-classes-with-similar-names)**"
Там был написан мини-плагин для jQuery, который подходит для вашего случая как нельзя лучше:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.removeClassWild = function(mask) {
        return this.removeClass(function(index, cls) {
            var re = mask.replace(/\*/g, '\\S+');
            return (cls.match(new RegExp('\\b' + re + '', 'g')) || []).join(' ');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Использование:

```
$("div").removeClassWild("status_*");
```

Результат:

`<div class="row1 td">`